# Index out of bounds because of numel MATLAB

Tags: matlab, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to create bit scales images. I am getting an error with this code. What is wrong?

```
clc
clear all
a=imread('image.tif');%read file


[row col]=size(a);%row of image and column of image
b=zeros(row,col,8);%3D 0 matrix

for k=1:8%position of bit
    for i=1:row%for every row
        for j=1:col%for every column
            bits = de2bi(a(i,j));
            b(i,j,k)=bits(k);
        end%endFor
    end%endFor
end%endFor

for k=1:8
    subplot(3,3,k);
    imshow(b(:,:,k));
    title(strcat(num2str(k),'. bit'));
end%endFor
```

ERROR:
??? Attempted to access bits(2); index out of bounds because numel(bits)=1.

Error in ==> soru1 at 13
                b(i,j,k)=bits(k);

Comment: Please copy the error into the question, *including* the stack trace with line numbers.  Also, is all of this code necessary to reproduce the problem?  (I suspect that neither the `clc` nor the `clear all` are necessary to reproduce it).

Comment: de2bi returns a vector like [1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1] in this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this line of code:

`bits = de2bi(a(i,j));`

You are calling `de2bi` on the value of the pixel at "i,j".  Presuming that the image you are opening is of type `uint8`, the value of `a(i,j)` can be anywhere between 0 and 255.  If these values are 0 or 1, the output of `de2bi` as you call it is just "0" or "1" - that is, it only has one element in it, and you cannot access the second, non-existent element.

To correct this, you need to force the size of the output of `de2bi` to be the size you require, which can be done using a second input, like this:

`bits = de2bi(a(i,j),8)`

In fact the loop isn't required since `de2bi`, like most MATLAB functions, can handle vectors or matrices as input, not just single numbers:

```
a=imread('image.tif');
b=de2bi(a);
b = reshape(de2bi,[size(a),8]);
```

Comment: I am trying your answer. It is running.

Comment: Note that `bits = de2bi(a(i,j),8)` pads the array with 0 to the right. Set the 3rd argument to 'left-msb' to pad from the left.